# Trying to retrieve the active monitor ID in Python

Tags: python, ctypes, maya

I was trying to retrieve the monitor ID in Python 2.7 via Maya. I was toying with `ctypes` as I couldn't find the right support in Python.  The idea is to retrieve an ID for the user's current monitor(in a multiple monitor environment), and parse the EDID dump that I created to retrieve the diagonal specs in inches for that monitor. I am trying to avoid using plug-ins as this will be used by an art team but obviously if there is no way around it then that is what has to be done.

***note**- I have also been able to determine mouse position via the following method.  Might be a way to calculate what I am looking for with that instead?

```
from ctypes import windll, Structure, c_ulong, byref


class POINT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_ulong), ("y", c_ulong)]



def queryMousePosition():
    pt = POINT()
    windll.user32.GetCursorPos(byref(pt))
    return { "x": pt.x, "y": pt.y}


pos = queryMousePosition()
print(pos)
```

Thanks in Advance

Cheers,
Capt. Solo

Comment: Look at [`GetForegroundWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505), [`MonitorFromWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145064), and [`GetMonitorInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144901).

Comment: By active do you mean where the mouse pointer is, or which monitor has the active window?

Comment: In order to complete @PeterWood question: where the mouse pointer is, which monitor has the active window, which monitor contains maya's main window or which monitor contains maya's active window (ie, script editor can be on monitor 1 while maya's main window can be on monitor 2)? 
We really need precisions so we can give you the most accurate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some possible answers to your question, I tried to only use "Python-only" code and not rely on any third-party library.

I couldn't find a way to get the physical size of the monitor using "Python-only" code.

I'll call my main screen, Monitor 1, the other one Monitor 2.

---

### A: Get which monitor has the current active window.

You can execute this from Maya's script editor, you'll get a different result depending on which monitor your script editor is.

**Doc:**

[GetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505)

[MonitorFromWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145064)

**Notes:**

> If the window intersects one or more display monitor rectangles, the
> return value is an HMONITOR handle to the display monitor that has the
> largest area of intersection with the window.
> If the window does not intersect a display monitor, the return value depends on the value of dwFlags.

**Code:**

```
from ctypes import windll

#Get active window id
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505
winID = windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
print "This is your current window ID: ",winID
# MonitorFromWindow constants 
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145064
MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL    = 0
MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY = 1
MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 2
monitorID = windll.user32.MonitorFromWindow(winID, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST)
print "This is your active monitor ID: ", monitorID
```

### B: Get which monitor has Maya's main window

You can also execute this from Maya's script editor, the result depends on which monitor Maya's main window is positionned. PySide is now included with the latest versions of Maya.

**Doc:**

[QWidget.winId()](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QWidget.winId)

**Code:**

```
import shiboken
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import maya.OpenMayaUI as apiUI

import ctypes

def getMayaWindow():
    """
    Get the main Maya window as a QtGui.QMainWindow instance
    @return: QtGui.QMainWindow instance of the top level Maya windows
    """
    ptr = apiUI.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    if ptr is not None:
        return shiboken.wrapInstance(long(ptr), QtGui.QWidget)

PyCObject_AsVoidPtr = ctypes.PYFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.py_object)(
                          ('PyCObject_AsVoidPtr', ctypes.pythonapi))

mayaID = PyCObject_AsVoidPtr(getMayaWindow().winId())
print "This is Maya's main window ID: ", mayaID

# MonitorFromWindow constants 
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145064
MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL    = 0
MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY = 1
MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 2
monitorID = windll.user32.MonitorFromWindow(mayaID, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST)
print "This is Maya's monitor ID: ", monitorID
```

### C: Get which monitor has the mouse pointer

**Doc:**

[MonitorFromPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145062(v=vs.85).aspx)

**Notes:**

> If the point is contained by a display monitor, the return value is an HMONITOR handle to that display monitor.
>
> If the point is not contained by a display monitor, the return value depends on the value of dwFlags.

**Code:**

```
from ctypes import windll, Structure, c_ulong, byref

class POINT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_ulong), ("y", c_ulong)]

def queryMousePosition():
    pt = POINT()
    windll.user32.GetCursorPos(byref(pt))
    return pt

mousePos = queryMousePosition()
print "This is your mouse position x: ", mousePos.x, " y:", mousePos.y

# MonitorFromPoint  constants 
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145062(v=vs.85).aspx
MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL    = 0
MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY = 1
MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 2
monitorID = windll.user32.MonitorFromPoint(pos, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST)
print "This is your active monitor ID: ", monitorID
```

Comment: The `POINT` structure is defined in the `ctypes.wintypes` module. Also, we can remove notes about X11 and OS X; I'll tag this question as Windows.

Comment: FYI, the default result type and integer argument of a ctypes function is a C `int`, while handles are pointer typedefs. However, in practice Windows limits kernel, user, and gdi handle values to less than 32-bit. So it's technically fine in this case that you didn't set `restype` and `argtypes` to use `HWND` and `HMONITOR` types.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to PySide or PyQt (which you should from within maya) you could use this simple snippet to get the id and position of each screen available:

```
dw = QtGui.QDesktopWidget()
screen_count = dw.numScreens()
for i in range(screen_count):
    rect_screen_i = dw.availableGeometry(i)
    print rect_screen_i
```